# Is there a prebuilt resource/widget for the "nice" indeterminate progress indicator in Android Wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

I mean this one:

[image]

(doesn't look as nice in the single screenshot, but it's much better than the default indeterminate progress -- in fact its shape and animation is pretty similar to the new "Material" indeterminate progress included in Android L, plus it changes colors).

There are no differences in `styles.xml` between the 19 and 20 platforms, and while there is a new `styles_micro.xml`, it doesn't seem to include this.

Answer (score 7):

Needed the same thing as you. Not sure if you found a solution that is part of android wear. Since I did not find a solution I did build my own. It is not perfect but as long as you do not study it frame by frame it should look correct.

I created it as it's own view. The code is not perfect and if someone like to improve it go ahead.

```
public class ProgressView extends ProgressBar {
    RectF rectF;
    Paint p;
    int start = 0;
    int maxvalue = 320;
    int value = 320;
    int[] currentColor = {0,0,0};
    boolean reverse = false;
    int nextcolor = 1;

    final int[][] colors = {
        {224,187,63},
        {224,46,25},
        {39,105,227},
        {51,130,49}
    };

    public ProgressView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ProgressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ProgressView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        p = new Paint();
        p.setStrokeWidth(6);
        p.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        p.setColor(Color.argb(255,colors[0][0], colors[0][1], colors[0][2]));
        currentColor = Arrays.copyOf(colors[0], colors[0].length);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        rectF = new RectF(0+5, 0+5, w-5, h-5);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c){
        if(reverse)
            start += 15;
        else
            start += 5;

        if(start == 360){
            start = 1;
        }
        if(!reverse)
            value -= 10;
        else
            value += 10;
        if(value == 0 || value == maxvalue){
            reverse = !reverse;
        }
        transformColor();
        p.setColor(Color.argb(255,currentColor[0], currentColor[1], currentColor[2]));
        c.drawArc(rectF, start, maxvalue - value, false, p);
        invalidate();
    }

    private void transformColor(){
        changeColors(0);
        changeColors(1);
        changeColors(2);
        if(currentColor[0] == colors[nextcolor][0] && currentColor[1] == colors[nextcolor][1] && currentColor[2] == colors[nextcolor][2]){
            if(nextcolor == 3)
                nextcolor = 0;
            else
                nextcolor++;
        }
    }

    private void changeColors(int i){
        if(currentColor[i] > colors[nextcolor][i]){
            currentColor[i] -= 1;
        }
        if(currentColor[i] < colors[nextcolor][i]){
            currentColor[i] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this can help someone. You could add more properties to it if you like but this is kind of the minimum solution that I found was working.

Comment: Great! I like it more than the default Lollipop one!